# Проблема с передачей POST

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

В общем смысл весь таков, есть три страницы, на которых вы сохраняете определенную инфу.
Они передаются через невидимые поля, и на третьей сохраняются в БД. Но Проблема в том, что когда вы ввели логин, который уже есть в БД, надо попросить пользователя ввести опять логин, но когда вы его направляете на другую страницу, все данные теряются.

Подскажите, как сделать проверку логина нормальную?

И можно как-то проверить на лету есть ли в БД такой логин?

Comment: Насколько я понял, вы хотите проверить существует ли такой же логин прямо "на лету"(бз отправки формы на сервер)?

Comment: да, можно так?

Comment: Да, можно. При помощи jQuery UI. Там плагин если не ошибаюсь называется Autocomplete. Посмотрите как-нибудь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите, чтобы все было красиво, то используйте **AJAX**. Все будет происходить на лету и на той же странице. Если точнее, то **AJAX** и **jQuery**. Я сам когда-то сталкивался с подобной задачей и это решение было самым оптимальным на мой взгляд. Для того, чтобы лучше разобраться, есть книжка(справочник) с множеством примеров (подобный также рассматривается). Книжка **"jQery"** Н.А.Прохоренок.

Желаю успехов :)

Comment: Скажите пож - вы юзали хоть что-то кроме JQuery? 

Если нет - зачем писать "ajax и jquery". Какбудто ajax - это фича jquery xD

Comment: Уж поверьте, я юзал много чего, и где я писал об AJAX как о фиче jQuery? Если не знаете, то и не говорите. У человека появилась трудность, я представил один из путей ее решения. И представил книгу, в которой именно такая связка (jQuery+Ajax) используется.

Comment: **Если не знаете, то и не говорите**

Если бы я не знал я бы не писал этого и предыдущего комментария.

Вы написали ** Если точнее, то AJAX и jQuery.** При этом вопрос то **Проблема с передачей POST**... 

Возможный путь ее решения - Ajax а не JQuery и Ajax. Печально что вы не понимаете разницы.

PS: поверьте мне - что такое ajax я знаю xD

Comment: Если не холиварить, то подитожу: Ajax нам понадобится для динамической обработки формы на сервере без презагрузки страницы(все хорошо), а красиво все это выдать нам позволит все тот же самый jQuery. Кстати, в вышенаписанном мной тексте был рекомендован справочник. Так вот в нем есть целая глава "Поддержка Ajax в jQuery", там же рассматривается функция POST.

Comment: Ну холиварность ответу вы предали сами...

Answer (score 0):

Используйте сессию

```
$_SESSION['login']=$_POST['login'];
```

это запишет переменную в куку, которую предоставил php. Подробнее тут: [функции обращения к сессиям](http://php.su/functions/?cat=session).

Comment: но ведь мне надо сохранять пороль, а такую информацию лучше не держать в куках

Comment: Сессия это типа кука, но не совсем. Сессия это типа кука на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

> а такую информацию лучше не держать в куках

А после проверки данных записывайте куке пустое значение и time() -99999 и все будет хорошо!

Т.Е. Есть операция которая проводит проверку данных, вот собственно в конце операции уничтожайте данные которые хранились в кухах для исполнения! За несколько минут куки никто не стырит!

Ну а говоря по другому, если кому-то нужно что-то скомуниздить, то для этого есть другие более эффективные методы.

Comment: спс так можно как-то проверить на лету есть ли в БД такой логин?